# Technical question about the fiber of tangent bundle over a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles

I am attempting to self-study differential geometry because it is relevant to my profession, but I have run into a technical question that I can't find addressed in the many textbooks out there.

Let $M$ be a manifold of degree $n$ and let $TM$ be the tangent bundle.
Since I don't know how to do commutative diagrams here, I'd like to refer to diagram (1) in this Wikipedia link: [Fiber Bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle).

With regard to that diagram, I am completely clear on the right hand side. My question concerns the left hand side. I know from various textbooks that a fiber $F$ of $TM$ is a vector space (isomorphic to $T_pM$). Furthermore, I know that $F=\pi^{-1}(p)$ at a point $p \in M$.

My question is what does $\pi^{-1}(p)$ look like? Note that this is before the homeomorphism to the Cartesian product $\{ p \} \times F$ is applied so it really can't be $(p,v)$. Furthermore, what is $\pi$? Most books call it a projection map, but it projects what onto what? It's clear from the diagram I cited that $\text{proj}_1$ is the projection map onto the first "slot" in the Cartesian product: $(p,v) \rightarrow p$. So what does $\pi$ project?

Finally, on the left hand side, what encodes information about $p$ so that the homeomorphism "knows" there is a $p$ to place in the first slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fiber at $p$ is not isomorphic to $T_pM$; it *is* the tangent space $T_pM$. To get a better feeling for things, suppose $M\subset \Bbb R^N$. Then
$$TM = \{(p,v)\in M\times\Bbb R^N: v\in T_pM\subset\Bbb R^N\},$$
and, yes, $\pi\colon TM\to M$ is literally given by $\pi(p,v) = p$.

Comment: I have a question. If $TM = \{ (p,v) \in M \times \mathbb {R^n}: v \in T_pM \subset \mathbb{R^n} \}$ then in that diagram what does the homeomorphism $\phi: \pi^{-1}(p) \rightarrow \{ p \} \times F$ do? (Again, I'm referring to Diagram (1) in the Wikipedia article). $F$ is the fiber over p which as you stated is $T_pM$.

Comment: This comes from parametrizing the open set $U\subset M$. Say $g\colon W\to U\subset M$ is a diffeomorphism of $W\subset\Bbb R^n$ with $U$. Then $dg_p: \Bbb R^n\to T_pM$ is an isomorphism and your $\phi\big|_{\pi^{-1}(p)}$ is the inverse of this isomorphism. Indeed, $dg\colon W\times\Bbb R^n \to \pi^{-1}(U)$, given by $dg(x,v) = dg_x(v)\in \{g(x)\}\times T_{g(x)}M$ is a diffeomorphism and $\phi$ is its inverse.

Answer (score 1):

a point, $p,$ in the tangent bundle is a point in the manifold together with a 
a vector, $v,$ which expresses a tangent distance and direction. $\pi$ expresses the action of dropping $v$ so you just have $p.$ The fibre at $p$ is the set of all the vectors that can be attached at $p$ so it is essentially a copy of $R^n.$ The subtleties lie in how the copies of $R^n$ join together.